# Probability that a ball is not picked in N realization

Tags: probability

Suppose we have N balls in a jar that are numbered 1,··· ,N.
We pick the ball randomly one at a time without replacement. What is the
probability that ball 1 is not picked in N realization of this experiment?

If we pick a ball without replacement N times, isn't there probability 0 that ball 1 is not picked? Since all N balls will be picked after N picks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. All balls have to be picked after $N$ turns.

Comment: The question says "without replacement" while you have interpreted it as "with replacement"

Comment: @Henry Ah, my bad. I've fixed my answer.